# дополнить строку символом, если она меньше другой на js

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Предположим, есть две строки: `1234` и `1234567`. Да, это именно строки. Как дополнить строку меньшей длины до ширины самой большой строки?

Comment: к 1234 добавить три нуля?

Comment: @Horchynskyi блин, андроид точку поставил. Проблема в пунктуации. Поправил

Answer (score 5, accepted):

не думаю что `replace`, это то что надо, так как реплейсить то нечего, предлагаю 
`padEnd\padStart` , в примере `10` это длина строки, которая должна получиться :

```js
var a = '123';

console.log(a.padEnd(10, '0'));
console.log(a.padStart(10, '0'));
```

Comment: `padEnd` - пока только в FF.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский у меня в хроме работает

Comment: значит в https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd что-то врут. в любом случае технология пока сыровата

Comment: @АлексейШиманский они не врут, они не знают :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский +1 в хроме работает 

@ RostyslavKuzmovych в подобных ответах не ленитесь давать ссылки на документацию (на MDN например)

Comment: @Darth спс за замечание, постараюсь не забыть. 
ПС: в едже тоже работает и в опере

Comment: @Darth хм. я просто не нашёл мест где точно это работает и в каких версиях, а раз на MDN была такая табличка, то я не стал писать этот вариант в своем ответе (точнее написал, но удалил :)).

Answer (score 6):

Пример без регулярок.

```js
var test = '123';
var repeatCount = 3;

console.log(test + '0'.repeat(repeatCount));
```

---

Немного обезьяничества

```js
String.prototype.rpad = function(padString, length) {
    var str = this;
    while (str.length < length)
        str = str + padString;
        
    return str;
}

var test = "123";
var totalCount = 6;

console.log(test.rpad("0", totalCount));

//-----------------------------------------
// обычная функция | взято с https://stackoverflow.com/a/13859571/6104996
function rpad(value, length) {
    return (value.toString().length < length) ? rpad(value + "0", length) : value;
}
console.log(rpad(test, totalCount));
```